# spark jobs with conditional filtering logic for multiple tenants

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

I have a table like

```
tenant_id,start_date,end_date,use_fancy_transformation
1,20180101,20180201,true
2,20180103,20180115,false
```

and a dataframe like

```
tenant_id,thing,date,value
1,1,20180105,1
2,2,20180107,2
1,2,20180120,2
```

Now there is some business logic which should perform different things (conditionally). The simplest case is exporting the data for the specified date range from the first table. Obviously, the date range is different for each tenant.

So when executing (in pseudocode) `df.filter(date between(tenant2_start, tenant2_end).write.partitionBy("tenant_id", "current_date").parquet` the filter is applied and content for tenant1 is lost.

Possible solutions I came up with (none really satisfies me, all seem clumsy):

- Not parallelizing the configuration table and then iterating on each entry. However, this might require some rather costly transformations to re-run (which optimally would be computed only once).
- Only doing the iterations on the config object after the costly transformations could be a possibility - but I do not think that would be a good solution as when the export for the first  tenant works but fails for the second one, then spark/ yarn will restart from scratch and recalculate both.
- Another possible solution would be to parametrize the configuration from outside via a workflow runner (like Oozie / Airflow), however, this triggers a lot of jobs (in case a lot of tenants are present). Remember the costly transformations.

**Do you see an elegant way out?**

Comment: Non eqi join as outlined in http://kirillpavlov.com/blog/2016/04/23/beyond-traditional-join-with-apache-spark/  looks really interesting.

Comment: Common sense => if your input table was _partitioned_ according to your needs, the data would already be segregated and you could run completely independant pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non eqi join works fine to solve the problem